# About JSON, WordPress blog and Android

Tags: android, json, eclipse, wordpress, blogs

how are you?

I have 2 questions...

First:

I just made a blog reader android application. And the data about blog posts is being returned in a format called JSON. I want to know if on WordPress happens the same thing. And how I can find this.

Second:

For now, Im using a local host for my WordPress blog, I would like to know where can I buy a domain, just a domain...

Thanks a lot, and sorry for my bad English, Im Brazilian, and I still learning :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fine. Thanks for asking.

1 - yes this is 100% doable. (I honestly cannot remember the steps, as I did it a year ago, but you would change what is the ourput of the page... from html to json I think)

2 - godaddy.com (and 3 zillion other sites, which can be easily googled)

enjoy coding.

Comment: Thanks for de the godaddy,com. It's gonna be very helpful. About my first question, I take JSON Data from an HTTP Request. I just wanna know if this is possible on WordPress Blog.

Comment: @LucasCastellani is the wordpress a custom made ?that is, you have downloaded it from wordpress.org or ur just using a wordpress.com blog ?

Comment: Im using wordpress.org for a better customize.

Comment: @LucasCastellani thats a good choice. I will update the answer. If you think it is right, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

A JSON API is being worked on as part of this year's Google Summer of Code project. Ryan McCue has his latest code [available as a plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/), and it'll be integrated into WordPress itself when he's done. But he's still trying to figure out exactly how it needs to work, so the API is still changing and it's not reliable enough to use in production.

Until that's ready, you're probably best off using [WordPress's XML-RPC API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API) or installing the [JSON API plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) developed by MoMa on the blog you're trying to pull content from.

As for where to buy a domains, there are pros & cons for wherever you choose. My best recommendation is to look for reviews and comments from people who have used them so you can get an idea of how they are to work with.